# How to use "attribute starting with" on multiple selector positions?

Tags: jquery, attributes

Is it possible to convert this code in a way that multiple element groups use it?

```
$("#name, #name_choice").hover(function(){
  $("#name, #name_choice").toggle();
});
$("#name_choice").change(function(){
  $("#name").html($(this).val());
})
```

So instead of copy paste this code and adjust the id tags I want to use, for example, the "attribute starts with" method. Is this even possible?

Comment: So in the above, it's `#name` and `#name_choice`, but you might want to use it with (say) `#foo` and `#foo_choice`?

Comment: exactly. so i want this code snippet for #name and #name_choice, but also for #foo and #foo_choice. so it might be easier if I use id tags that start at least with the same characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, probably simplest to wrap it up as a function:

```
function setupThingy(mainId, choiceId) {
    var main = $("#" + mainId);
    var choice = $("#" + (choiceId ? choiceId : mainId + "_choice"));
    var both = main.add(choice);
    both.hover(function(){
      both.toggle();
    });
    choice.change(function(){
      main.html($(this).val());
    });
}
```

And then:

```
setupThingy("name");
```

---

Ideally, if you can relate them structurally rather than giving them each `id`s, that might be cleaner...

Comment: Don't know why, but with this solution it hovers continuously when the mouse is moving over the elements.

Maybe this helps:

                      <div id="test">Test</div>
                      <div>
                          <select id="test_choice" style="display:none">
                              <option>1</option>
                              <option>2</option>
                           </select>
                      </div>

Comment: @Chris: I had an editing error, `+ "_name"` instead of `+ "_choice"`. Fixed now. If that's not it, please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).